# Pascal Object: how to do a typed forward declaration?

Tags: delphi, object, pascal

I'm translating the great fmod C header to Pascal, and I'm stuck because of a forward declaration.
If I declare the function *before* the type, the error is "FMOD_CODEC_STATE: unknown", and if I declare the FMOD_CODEC_STATE *before* the function, the error is "FMOD_CODEC_METADATACALLBACK: unknown"
Any idea how I could solve this problem?
Thank you very much !

```
type
  FMOD_CODEC_STATE = Record
    numsubsounds: Integer;
    waveformat: array[0..0] of FMOD_CODEC_WAVEFORMAT;
    plugindata: Pointer;

    filehandle: Pointer;
    filesize: Cardinal;
    fileread: FMOD_FILE_READCALLBACK;
    fileseek: FMOD_FILE_SEEKCALLBACK;
    metadata: FMOD_CODEC_METADATACALLBACK;
  end;
  FMOD_CODEC_METADATACALLBACK    = function (codec_state: FMOD_CODEC_STATE; tagtype: FMOD_TAGTYPE; name: PChar; data: Pointer; datalen: Cardinal; datatype: FMOD_TAGDATATYPE; unique: Integer):FMOD_RESULT;
```

Comment: Bad code sample - no need for forward declaration here, the problem is somewhere before.

Comment: You're right. The function was the wrong one. I've corrected my question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Btw I'm not sure that `array[0..0]` does what you think it does.

Comment: @Blindy is right. The C code declares `waveformat` as a *pointer* to an FMOD_CODEC_WAVEFORMAT, and you should do the same. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The record doesn't need to be passed by value. In fact, the original C code doesn't pass it by value anyway. It's passed by reference, with a pointer. Declare the pointer, then the function, and then the record:

```
type
  PFMOD_CODEC_STATE = ^FMOD_CODEC_STATE;
  FMOD_CODEC_METADATACALLBACK = function (codec_state: PFMOD_CODEC_STATE; tagtype: FMOD_TAGTYPE; name: PChar; data: Pointer; datalen: Cardinal; datatype: FMOD_TAGDATATYPE; unique: Integer):FMOD_RESULT;
  FMOD_CODEC_STATE = Record
    numsubsounds: Integer;
    waveformat: PFMOD_CODEC_WAVEFORMAT;
    plugindata: Pointer;

    filehandle: Pointer;
    filesize: Cardinal;
    fileread: FMOD_FILE_READCALLBACK;
    fileseek: FMOD_FILE_SEEKCALLBACK;
    metadata: FMOD_CODEC_METADATACALLBACK;
  end;
```

Yes, you're allowed to declare a pointer to something before you've declared the thing it points to. You're not allowed to forward-declare records, though, so the order given above is the only possible order for those three declarations.

Comment: I've found a strange behavior: if I copy/paste your code, it works. If I add the keyword "type" once again **just before** FMOD_CODEC_STATE = Record there is an error raised: "identifier not declared: FMOD_CODEC_STATE" (Delphi 2007). Is that behavior normal?

Comment: Yes, that's normal. All forward-declared types must be resolved before the end of the current "type" section. You'll also see this if you forward-declare a class with `TFoo = class;` — you need to fully declare `TFoo` before you declare any non-type identifiers (like functions, variables, or constants).

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Pascal has automatic forward type declaration for pointer classes, which is what I'm assuming that function actually takes. So simply changing your declarations to something like this (warning, I haven't used pascal in over 12 years) should work:

```
type
  PFMOD_CODEC_STATE=^FMOD_CODEC_STATE;
  FMOD_CODEC_METADATACALLBACK    = function (codec_state: PFMOD_CODEC_STATE; tagtype: FMOD_TAGTYPE; name: PChar; data: Pointer; datalen: Cardinal; datatype: FMOD_TAGDATATYPE; unique: Integer):FMOD_RESULT;

  FMOD_CODEC_STATE = Record
    numsubsounds: Integer;
    waveformat: array[0..0] of FMOD_CODEC_WAVEFORMAT;
    plugindata: Pointer;

    filehandle: Pointer;
    filesize: Cardinal;
    fileread: FMOD_FILE_READCALLBACK;
    fileseek: FMOD_FILE_SEEKCALLBACK;
    metadata: FMOD_CODEC_METADATACALLBACK;
  end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, you've answered like Rob Kennedy... but he was quicker ;) Thank you anyway!