# Forward declarations for record types (or arrays)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I want to do this in XE5:

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    // fields
    class function GetList: TMyRecArr; static;
  end;

  TMyRecArr = array of TMyRec;
```

I've already seen ["Forward declarations for record types"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344358/forward-declarations-for-record-types) and ["how to do a typed forward declaration?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018510/pascal-object-how-to-do-a-typed-forward-declaration), but they seem irrelevant since my problem is not passing the record as a parameter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot use a forward declaration to declare a record type or an array type. But not to fear. You can use a generic dynamic array, `TArray<T>`.

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    class function GetList: TArray<TMyRec>; static;
  end;
```

This is actually better than declaring `TMyRecArr` as per the code in your question. That's because the generic `TArray<T>` has more flexible type identity than a traditional dynamic array type. You can use `TArray<T>` with generic types defined in libraries that are independent and unaware of your code.

Now, you could declare the type like this:

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    type TMyRecArray = array of TMyRec;
    class function GetList: TMyRecArray; static;
  end;
```

And then your array type is `TMyRec.TMyRecArray`. But I urge you not to do this. You'll have a type that can only be used with you code, and cannot be used with third party code.

In summary, `TArray<T>` is your friend.

Comment: Well, there's always faking it by defining a pointer type such as `PMyRec`.

Comment: @JerryDodge Er, I don't think so. Not going to play well with type safety, code readability or reference counting.

Comment: True, but just for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237268/how-to-declare-record-containing-events-which-use-record-as-parameter

Comment: @JerryDodge That's quite different. Type safe. What we have here is not amenable to that approach.

Comment: It's not "better" it's just different.  The advantages of TArray<T> accrue to TArray<T>, not to the code using TArray<T>.  It's like saying that driving to work is better because cars can also be used to travel to other places.  Suitable, yes.  An answer to the problem, yes.  "Better" ?  Meaningless (as stated).  Of course it's better than something that doesn't work at all, but for that reason alone.  Also worth bearing in mind is the confidence you can have in an approach: generics in Delphi have been plagued with problems from the outset and continue to suffer **serious** regressions.

Comment: @Deltics No, it's better. The benefits of type compatibility are immense. They allow composability between different libraries, something that is impossible with non-generic dynamic arrays. Yes generics have been plagued with problems, but few relating to `TArray<T>`. I know that I have been using `TArray<T>` extensively with success.

Answer (score 1):

Since declarations of pointers types are permitted before the type definition, slightly modifying your function you're allowed to do this:

```
type
  PMyRecArr = ^TMyRecArr;

  TMyRec = record
    // fields
    class procedure GetList(const arr: PMyRecArr); static;
  end;

  TMyRecArr = array of TMyRec;
```

The procedure implementation and its usage follow:

```
class procedure TMyRec.GetList(const arr: PMyRecArr);
begin
  SetLength(arr^, 4);
end;

var
  arr: TMyRecArr;

begin
  TMyRec.GetList(@arr);
  Writeln(Length(arr));//prints 4
end.
```

Comment: Take a look at my comments on David's answer.

Comment: @JerryDodge I saw the comments but your focus was about pointers to `TMyRec` if I'm not misunderstanding. The reference counting and the type safety are pointless in my answer

Comment: Are you recommending this as best practise?

Comment: That's still more or less the same concept as my linked question (using pointers)

Comment: @JerryDodge I'd assumed that you meant replacing `TMyRecArr` with `Pointer` and casting, FWIW.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it's a possibility without using generics. What if the OP relies on a compiler version which does not have them? In my real case, I'm currently at home with *Turbo Delphi*. Not so bad to be downvoted in my opinion :)

Comment: I meant mocking the "forward declaration" by using `PMyRecArr = ^TMyRecArr;` After all, that's what the question's title indicates.

Comment: @fant The question states XE5. Not only is the forced use of pointers a bad idea, but you've replace function return value with parameter. That greatly reduces the flexibility of the method since now it can't be used as an assignment rhs, an argument, and so on.

Comment: Me too, but the moment someone corrects me, I go and re-read more carefully to see why.

Comment: @JerryDodge *That's still more or less...* ok but the linked question are about `Pointer` and records and the OP says *my problem is not passing the record as a parameter.* I agree with what you meant but you wrote and linked another stuff. More or less but different, so I thought to post my answer because it seemed to me that no one have focus on the array and its pointer. This is only to explain my point of view. I re-read too but I missed XE5 again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I searched a little more, and found that I can use helpers to do this:

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    // fields
  end;

  TMyRecArr = array of TMyRec;

  TMyRecHelper = record helper for TMyRec
    class function GetList: TMyRecArr; static;
  end;
```

Sure it lacks benefits of generics that David mentioned in his answer and comments, but it doesn't make the code auto-complete unusable! I mean one may comes to this conclusion that the flexibility that `TArray<T>` offers is not needed in some piece of code. Then it would be nothing more than [increment in memory usage of the final running application or possibly lower performance](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Overview_of_Generics).

Comment: That would be an erroneous conclusion. Memory usage for `TArray<T>` instantiation is not an issue. No copies of code generated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is it the same about all generic arrays, `TArray<TMyRec>` for example? And, if you don't call it a new question, how do you evaluate using record helpers in this case?

Comment: The increase in memory usage is due to code bloat with multiple copies of identical code for each generic instantiation. That's not an issue with a generic dynamic array. No code bloat. There's nothing to be scared of with generic dynamic arrays. They are your friend!

Comment: Record helpers are are useful trick when facing circular references. I've used them when I have `TRecA` and `TRecB` where `TRecA` has `TRecB` args/return types  and `TRecB` has `TRecA` args/return types. You can also use them to inject constants  into a record's namespace where the constant is a typed constant of that record's type.

Comment: However, you don't need to use helpers here, and probably should avoid doing so. Only one helper at a time can be active. You've got one bullet. Only use it if you absolutely have to. That's the big downside with helpers as you use them. You don't need to, there's no benefit, there's complexity, and you limit yourself in the future in multiple ways. The generic dynamic array is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to add forward decalrations to records (which up until now still isn't possible in Delphi), there is a way around this : move functions that reference another record type towards a record helper, declared where both record types are in scope.

```
type
  RecordA = record
    // [...]
  end;

  RecordB = record
    // [...]
  end;

  RecordAHelper = record helper for RecordA
    procedure Call(argument: RecordB);
  end;
```

After obvioulsy implementing this, above allows one to write (and compile and run) : `RecordA_variable.Call(RecordB_variable)`

Comment: Are you suggesting something different than what I said in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32876651/2093077)?

Comment: I only noticed your answer just now, it seems we're basically suggesting the same work-around, indeed. Ah well, it doesn't hurt to have two descriptions.