# set parameter of record inside record and viceversa - Delphi

Tags: delphi

I would like to know how to declare a record parameter which is another record, and declare the same record inside of the other record.

Example :

```
  record1 = record
    param1 : Byte;
    param2 : Byte;
    param3 : ^record2;
  end;

  record2 = record
    param1 : Byte;
    param2: Byte;
    param3 : record1;
  end;
```

When I do this, the compiler says identifier redeclared, I don't know why.

Comment: Take a look at this [question - answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848994/forward-declarations-for-record-types-or-arrays). Does it (or the linked related Q-A) include the answer to your question?

Comment: i got working with making pointer upside the record and it works! but when check the record info in the parameter says erroneous type but the compiler works now

is that an issue? or just its an bug ?

Comment: You need a forward declaration for record2
`PRecord2 = ^record2; record1=record ... param3: PRecord2; record2=record ...`

Comment: hi, thanks i already fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue making pointer upside the 2 records.

```
PRecord1 = ^record1;
PRecord2 = ^record2;

record1 = record
  param1 : Byte;
  param2 : Byte;
  param3 : PRecord2;
end;

record2 = record
  param1 : Byte;
  param2: Byte;
  param3 : PRecord1;
end;
```